# ContentPage title doesn't work on .NET MAUI Android application

Tags: android, .net, xaml, maui

I try to create a title image for MAUI Android application, but the title is not visible. Even if I change with a label, same result:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ChapsPizza.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ChapsPizza.ViewModels"
             Title="Test">
    
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label Text="Test" TextColor="Black"/>
        <!--<Image Source="logo.png" Background="Orange"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40"/>-->
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

</ContentPage>
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you navigate to this page can you show me

Comment: it's main page, if i create another label outside of TitleView  i see it

Comment: May I know what is your Visual Studio version? You need to update to at least `17.3.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This potential issue is being fixed and tracked on this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3877

I tested it using `Visual Studio 17.3.5` and the `label` in the `TitleView` was shown in the contentpage.

**Update:**

In your **AppShell.xaml.cs**, change it like below:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Comment: same result, my version of Visual Studio is 17.3.6

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link? I will help you to check why it's not working on your side.

Comment: https://github.com/ClaudiuAndries/-Minimal-Reproducible-Example this is project

Comment: See my update in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Shell.TitleView

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Label Text="Test" TextColor="Black"/>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

As I understand we should not use NavigationPage but I'm not sure.

> NavigationPage is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps, and an exception will be thrown if you attempt to use NavigationPage in a Shell app. For more information about Shell apps, see Shell.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: That only works with Shell pages, AFAIK. The OP seems to be using a `NavigationPage`, so Shell might not be involved here.